# Is it possible to create different log files policies for different events?

Tags: windows, event-viewer

I am using windows server 21H2 to audit the access to a folder, files and subfolders.

If in event viewer I right click in security and go to properties, I can configure the size of the event files and to select if I want to archive or overwrite old records. I have choosen overwrite old records and the size of the logs the default value, 20MB.

I have realized, that more or less, in 3 hours, it was created about 20 files of 20MB, about 400MB, so it is too big. I guess it is beacuse it is record all security events in the same log.

So I was wondering if I could configure different policies to save the logs. I would like to have one policy for events 4660 and 4663 that are for access to files and another polcies for the rest, excluding the other two events. So I could give more space for the events 4660 and 4663 and leave the default for the rest.

Is it possible to create different policies for security events?